# WCF Service call another service in background

Tags: wcf

I want to call a web service from another web service in a non-blocking way. I've implemented this by using BackgroundWorker. But, I'm not sure whether this is the best way to do.

**Scenario:**
I call a web service Service_A which performs certain task & has to inform another web service Service_B about the changes made. I call the Service_B's one-way function NotifyUpdates for handling the updates. Service_A doesn't waits for Service_B's response & continues with its task. The response from the Service_B is logged in the background.

My question is, what is the best way to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BackgroundWorker is purposed for UI use, and I don't think it's the best way to use it here.

If you are using .Net 4 better to use [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx)

```
var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoServiceBCall());
```

If not,use [ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem.aspx) or [Thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx)

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(DoServiceBCall));
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

First of all, based on your scenario, if call to Service B is one way, Service A will not receive any response from Service-B except Http Status code (if call to service-B is on Http).

I'd call Service-B asynchronously to keep the things and code simple.

HTH,
Amit

Comment: I'm calling the Service_B asynchronously. I wasn't sure what to use for asynchronous call and thought there might be better way to do this. As mentioned in the above answer there is Task, ThreadPool & BackgroundWorker (which I was using).